# Arm64 cannot use Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net

Arm32/Arm64 SDK Compare： 
[image]

[image]

I have an Asp.net core project, Requirements must be run on the Arm64 development board.

release, Using framework dependencies：

SDK can't run Asp.net Core application...
If using a separate release
arm64

[image]
arm32

[image]

Although an error is reported on the arm32 bit (default configuration problem), the application can be run.

I have to run the Asp.net Core app on an Arm 64 development board, help me...

Comment: fyi https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/82

Comment: I can't see any of your image and I really hope this is not an images of text. dotnet perfectly run on arm64, are you sure, that you correctly install .net SDK?